# Finding the zeroes of finite exponential sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, roots

I want to find the zeroes for functions that look like this (an example):$$f(t) = k_1e^\left(a_1t\right)+k_2e^\left(a_2t\right)+k_3e^\left(a_3t\right) ,$$where all $a_i$ are negative real numbers, so this sum always converges to zero at infinity. With two factors of $k$, I can simply compare both and solve it algebrically. However, I am stuck with how to do it with 3 or more factors.
This may probably be a stupid question, but it doesn't ring any bells and I couldn't find anything related on a web search.

Thank you.

Comment: In the case of two terms, I presume you have one of the k's being positive and the other negative; otherwise, if both have the same sign, the sum has no zeroes, since $e^{at} > 0$ for any value of $a$.  I believe there is no "exact" solution for three or more terms, since exponential functions are transcendental; zeroes would generally need to be found using numerical methods, except in very special cases.

Comment: In 1883, Laguerre has extended usual Descrates' rule of sign and covered this sort of sums. If you order $a_i$ in ascending or descending order, then the number of real roots is equal or small than the number of sign changes in $k_i$. In case it is smaller, the difference is an even number. Laguerre's paper can be found [here](http://sepwww.stanford.edu/oldsep/stew/laguerre.pdf).